# User agent regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, user-agent

I'm almost embarrassed to ask, but just almost. I seem to have an expression that works already, but it only seem to work in various regex tools like Regulator or online tools. Once in my C# code, it fails to hit where it should.

So the issue is that I need the regex to hit on user agent strings containing "android", "iphone" or "ipod", but not those also containing "opera". Simple enough, right?

So far, I've got this:

```
^(?=.*?\b(android|iphone|ipod)\b)(?!opera).*$
```

I'm using following options

```
RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline
```

Please tell me where I got it wrong.

Here are some user agent strings. The expression should trigger on first and last, while ignore the two in the middle:

```
Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+2.2;+nb-no;+Nexus+One+Build/FRF91)+AppleWebKit/533.1+(KHTML,+like Gecko)+Version/4.0+Mobile+Safari/533.1
Opera/9.80 (Android; Linux; Opera Mobi/ADR-1012221546; U; pl) Presto/2.7.60 Version/10.5
Opera/9.80 (J2ME/iPhone;Opera Mini/5.0.019802/886; U; ja)Presto/2.4.15
Mozila/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Geckto) Version/3.0 Mobile/3A101a Safari/419.3
```

Thanks

Comment: Hye, I would try to test on: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx -> then when you can manage a match -> you'll get generated C# string code. btw. In this tester I didn't get a match..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you remembered to add a "@" in front of the pattern string? If not, the "\b" will be interpreted as a backspace.

Also as some say, you are not checking for Opera anywhere but in the beginning of the line, is that on purpose? I would probably use this syntax instead:
`@"^(?!opera)(?=.*\b(android|iphone|ipod)\b).*$"`

Comment: Great tip, word boundaries were not there to begin with, so the string was not prefixed with the "@". You're the man!

Comment: You're welcome. That's an easy mistake to make when coming from a regex tool and using it in C#. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Negative look-aheads are tricky](http://yacsharpblog.blogspot.com/2008/09/regular-expressions-in-c-negative-look.html). In short, you're only rejecting strings that do not contain opera at the start of the string (corrected, thanks @stema). Honestly, to keep from having the confusion often associated with look-ahead, you might want to break this into two parts:

**Option 1:**

Use the regex without lookahead, plus `String.Contains()`

> Regex myRegex = "(?i)(android|iphone|ipod)"; //case insensitive
>
> bool isUserStringNonOperaMobile = myRegex.isMatch(userString) && !userString.ToLower().Contains("opera");

**Option 2:**

Use two regexes

> Regex myRegex = "(?i)(android|iphone|ipod)"; //case insensitive
>
> Regex myOtherRegex = "(?i)opera"; // case insensitive
>
> bool isUserStringNonOperaMobile = myRegex.isMatch(userString) && !myOtherRegex.isMatch(userString);

Yes, these might be slightly less efficient, but its negligible, and what you lose in efficiency, you gain in readability and maintainability.

Comment: Thats not true, he is checking for `opera` only at the beginning of the string. Every look ahead is starting to match from the beginning of the string.

Comment: Got it. I don't use lookaheads often because they can be confusing, and because some languages don't support them (maybe that's not as true anymore, but you'll find a number of programmers who still avoid them).

Comment: I did consider splitting the regex into two, but that was thrown out as it involved introducing too much unnecessary complexity.

Comment: And I would say that using a lookahead where two simple regexps would work is introducing too much unnecessary complexity. It's a matter of perspective and personal style, really, but I work with regexps on a daily basis (my daily work is 90% Perl), and I still find lookaheads to frequently be unreadable. They would probably never pass in a review in my code unless they really were necessary. Whether you use them or not is up to you, but consider that if you or another developer has trouble with the code, the correct solution may, once again, be non-obvious with a single regexp.

Comment: The mentioned complexity lies in having to change the object and data model and that the expression is a configurable value. That would also mean having to extend the UI which would become too complex to handle. Besides, we couldn't just keep adding fields and UI elements for every new thing we want to include/exclude.

Comment: Fair enough. I would still likely handle this differently, but I'm not going to nitpick your likely equally-valid design decisions. I was just pointing out that "unnecessary complexity" is a very subjective thing, and can refer to code maintainability as well as actual logic.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for `opera` only at the very beginning of the string. Is that intended?

Every look ahead tries to match from the start. You bind it to `^` and then your lookahead is only `opera`, no other characters allowed before.

Try

```
^(?=.*?\b(android|iphone|ipod)\b)(?!.*opera).*$
```

to check for `opera` somewhere in the string.

Comment: You are correct, that was not intended. However, that was not what was causing this, as it just so happens that Opera UAs also start with "Opera". But nicely spotted and thanks for that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with c# but are you sure it supports the `?!` construct?